# Firebiard2.5+Delphi+IBObjects - invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)

Tags: delphi, firebird

Есть простенький проект на Delphi7 с компонентами IBO - `IB_Connection` и `IB_DSQL`. Если `IB_DSQL` использовать без `IB_Transaction`, то всё отрабатывает идеально. Но так делать автор IBO не рекомендует.
А как только я прописываю в свойстве `IB_DSQL.IB_Transaction` ссылку на компонент `IB_Transaction`, мой `IB_DSQL` падает сразу на `Prepare` по экзцепшну: "*invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)*", даже если я перед `Prepare` делаю `Transaction.StartTransaction` {?}. Хотя `Transaction.InTransaction` показывает `true`.

Вот фрагмент кода. Строка, на которой падает, помечена {!}.

```
with dsqlSaveNewOrder do begin
  IB_Transaction.StartTransaction;  {?}

  if not Prepared then
    Prepare;               {!}

  ParamByName('aRef_Id').AsInteger :=ARefId;
  ParamByName('aName').AsString := AName;

  ExecSQL;

  if FieldByName('err').AsInteger <> 0 then begin
    IB_Transaction.Rollback;

    Result := -1971;
    WLog('ERROR: '+FieldByName('msg').AsString);
  end
  else begin
    IB_Transaction.Commit;

    Result := FieldByName('oId').AsInteger;
    WLog('Order #'+IntToStr(ARefId)+' "'+AName+'" saved in local storage');
  end;
end;
```

Вот SQL, который прописан в IB_DSQL.SQL:

```
    execute procedure saveNewOrder(:aRef_Id,:aName)
```

Или такой SQL, но с аналогичным результатом:

```
    select oId,err,msg
    from saveNewOrder(:aRef_Id,:aName)
```

Свойства всех компонентов выставлены по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

Решилось просто: удалением `IB_Transaction` с формы и сознанием новой `IB_Transaction` c тем же самым Name и с теми же всеми остальными свойствами, которые, как и в изначальном варианте, были все по умолчанию. 

Итого: Если компонент ведёт себя "странно", имеет смысл пересоздать его.